# Angular returning 404 when requesting

Tags: angular, typescript

There is no error in code  , the problem is when there is no data in the database and I tried to request it is returning 404 but when there is data on the database then no error is shown , how do we handle this ?

I don't wanna return a 404 error when there is no data on the database when requesting. If no data in the datatabse then dont return any error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUiAf.png)

#Code

```
private _pageEventDealsForApprovalList() {
    this.searchInput = '';
    const status = 'ForApproval'
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        status,
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe({
        error: (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err),
        next: (res) => {
          this.table.data = res.items;
          this.todalDealsForApproval = res.items.length;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.trasactionService.transactionEvent.next({
              sendData: this.todalDealsForApproval,
              operation: 'transaction/update/count'
            });
          }, 1000);
        },
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

Comment: This should handle from API side. If data not exist you can return NoContent (204) or Ok (200)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch), which you could use to solve your problem. This operator will transform your error and return another value instead (e.g. `EMPTY` from the rxjs-namespace if you don't want to return anything in case something goes wrong).

This might not be a good idea in all cases, since this silently swallows the error (albeit in your example, you're displaying the error message). You might only want to do this on certain error types, or as mentioned in the comment by @Yaseer to your original question, return some sort of empty result set from the backend instead.

```
private someMethod {
    this.removedForBrevity()
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          this.notificationService.showError(err);
          return EMPTY;
        }),
        finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false))
      )
      .subscribe({
        error: noop,
        next: (res) => {
          this.table.data = res.items;
          this.todalDealsForApproval = res.items.length;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.trasactionService.transactionEvent.next({
              sendData: this.todalDealsForApproval,
              operation: 'transaction/update/count'
            });
          }, 1000);
        },
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

Comment: Hi , what empty result Ill be putting and assiging on the return EMPTY;?

Comment: `EMPTY` doesn't emit any value, so the callback for `next` is not called at all.